# Как сделать в 1 файле бесконечный цикл и бот телеграм на Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Идея в том чтобы получать данные по АПИ каждые 10 минут (Бесконечный цикл с time.sleep(600). Обновление данных и хранение их в переменных), а потом используя модуль aiogram (В том же файле с бесконечным циклом) по запросу человека в телеграм боте кидать ему останнюю обновлённую информацию. (Не могу сделать каждный запрос к АПИ под каждного человека т.к. у сервиса ограничение по запросам 1 раз в 10 минут, а для бота всем юзерам нужна одна  и та же информация)

Comment: Приведите пример кода, и что именно не получается добавить (или обрабатывать в цикле).

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import time
from threading import Thread


class MyThread(Thread):
    """
    A threading example
    """

    def __init__(self, name):
        """Инициализация потока"""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        """Запуск потока"""
        amount = random.randint(3, 15)
        time.sleep(amount)
        msg = "%s is running" % self.name
        print(msg)


def create_threads():
    """
    Создаем группу потоков
    """
    for i in range(5):
        name = "Thread #%s" % (i + 1)
        my_thread = MyThread(name)
        my_thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_threads()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать модуль `threading`. Вот пример:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

a=0
threads=[]
def func1():
    global a
    while True:
        a+=1; print(f'\nfunc1 {a}\n')
        sleep(1)

def func2():
    global a
    while True:
        a+=10; print(f'\nfunc2 {a}\n')
        sleep(2)

thread1=Thread(target=func1); threads.append(thread1)
thread2=Thread(target=func2); threads.append(thread2)
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```